# Can anyone help me identify this component? SMD P636

Tags: identification, bms

I damaged a BMS board by briefly shorting some connector leads. The only chips I see that appear physically damaged at the two marked by the red box in the image below. I can't seem to find those components in my usual places. Anyone have ideas that could point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help. Any suggestions would be welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are 18V unidirectional TVS diodes: **SMBJ18A**.

Their marking code is LT, not P636.